# In pandas, how can I get a DataFrame as the output while I sum the DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

While I sum a `DataFrame`, it returns a `Series`:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 3]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
      a  b  c
   0  1  2  3
   1  2  3  3

   In [4]: s = df.sum()

   In [5]: type(s)
   Out[5]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

I know I can construct a new `DataFrame` by this `Series`. But, is there any more "pandasic" way?

Comment: I think `pd.DataFrame({'my_sum': df.sum()})` is pandasic enough. This gives you the possibility to "name" your sum.

Comment: Although not cleaner, `pd.DataFrame(np.sum(df.values, axis=1), columns=['my_sum'])` should be notably faster...

Comment: +1 for pandastic, but I think the answer is no :(

Answer (score 13):

I'm going to go ahead and say... "No", I don't think there is a direct way to do it, the pandastic way (and pythonic too) is to be explicit:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.sum(), columns=['sum'])
```

or, more elegantly, using a dictionary (be aware that this copies the summed array):

```
pd.DataFrame({'sum': df.sum()})
```

*As @root notes it's faster to use:*

```
pd.DataFrame(np.sum(df.values, axis=0), columns=['sum'])
```

(As the zen of python states: "practicality beats purity", so if you care about this time, use this).

*However, perhaps the **most** pandastic way is to just use the Series!* :)

.

Some `%timeit`s for your tiny example:

```
In [11]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(df.sum(), columns=['sum'])
1000 loops, best of 3: 356 us per loop

In [12]: %timeit pd.DataFrame({'sum': df.sum()})
1000 loops, best of 3: 462 us per loop

In [13]: %timeit  pd.DataFrame(np.sum(df.values, axis=0), columns=['sum'])
1000 loops, best of 3: 205 us per loop
```

and for a slightly larger one:

```
In [21]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100000, 3), columns=list('abc'))

In [22]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(df.sum(), columns=['sum'])
100 loops, best of 3: 7.99 ms per loop

In [23]: %timeit pd.DataFrame({'sum': df.sum()})
100 loops, best of 3: 8.3 ms per loop

In [24]: %timeit  pd.DataFrame(np.sum(df.values, axis=0), columns=['sum'])
100 loops, best of 3: 2.47 ms per loop
```

Comment: Ah, so we've settled on "pandastic"?  Works for me ("pandarrific", which I also liked, doesn't have the "s".)

Comment: @DSM "pandarrific" seems a bit too much like "horrific" (rather than terrific)... No ambiguity in pandastic, I think I'm sold! :)

Comment: Andy, thank you for the reply. I temporarily leave the problem open to wait other possible answer. Will accept in a few days if no other answers.

Answer (score 12):

Often it is necessary not only to convert the sum of the columns into a dataframe, but also to transpose the resulting dataframe. There is also a method for this:

```
df.sum().to_frame().transpose()
```

Comment: Or you can just write `.T` instead of `.transpose()` for the sake of compactness: `df.sum().to_frame('sum').T`

Answer (score 7):

You can use `agg` for simple operations like `sum`, have a look at how compact this is:

```
df.agg(['sum'])
```

However, this can come at a significant performance cost. Consider other solutions when shorter execution times are more important than shorter code lines.

Comment: i really like the syntax, but unfortunately in my use case it caused a __major__ performance issue. i rewrote `df.any(axis=1)` as `df.agg(["any"], axis=1)` and it took almost a minute to run on a medium sized dataframe. switching back brought back normal run time. i know this is just anecdotal evidence, but perhaps will save others some confusion.

Comment: @lunguini Thank you for your performance insights, I had no idea this could cause such major slowdowns! Updated my answer to warn about performance costs.

Comment: @lunguini For the sake of definiteness, could you share how much was your normal run time, approximately? A couple of seconds, or maybe less than a second?

Comment: here's a full example:

```
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

rng = np.random.default_rng()
df = pd.DataFrame(data=rng.integers(0, 2, size=(10_000, 10)))
t0 = time.perf_counter()
df.any(axis=1).to_frame().transpose()
t1 = time.perf_counter()
df.agg(['any'], axis=1)
t2 = time.perf_counter()
print("any.to_frame.transpose", t1 - t0)
print("agg", t2 - t1)
# any.to_frame.transpose 0.0012745661661028862
# agg 3.5748125459067523
```

Comment: on my laptop `any.to_frame.transpose` takes 0.002 s `agg` takes 3.58 s

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure about earlier versions, but as of pandas 0.18.1 one can use [pandas.Series.to_frame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) method.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 3]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
s = df.sum().to_frame(name='sum')

type(s)

>>> pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

The `name` argument is optional and defines the column name.

Answer (score 3):

`df.sum().to_frame()` should do what you want.

See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html.

Answer (score 0):

By `DF.sum().to_frame()` or storing aggregate results directly to Dataframe, is not a healthy option. More importantly when you want to store aggregate value and aggregate sum separate. Using DF.sum().to_frame will store values and sum together.

Try below for cleaner version.

```
a = DF.sum()
sum = list(a)
values = list(a.index)

Series_Dict = {"Agg_Value":values, "Agg_Sum":sum}

Agg_DF = pd.DataFrame(Series_Dict)
```